# wait for Array.map to finish before completing Observer

Tags: angular, observable

I having this issue where I am calling an observable which will get a list from server, and then I do some mapping on the list to format it to desired UI format. However, before the map is done observer is completing, and hence I am not finding a value that is present in the list.

Code below.

```
loadContacts(id: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.sampleSvc
        .getList(id)
        .subscribe(contacts => {

          this.contactList = contacts.map(item => {
            return {
              id: item.Id,
              item: item.Description
            };
          });

          observer.next(true);
          observer.complete();
        }, error => {

          observer.next(false);
          observer.complete();
        });
    });
}

HandleSave(contactId: number) {
   if (contactId && contactId > 0) {
      this.loadContacts(this.id).subscribe(result => {
        this.selectedContact = this.contactList.find(item => item.id == contactId);
        this.inputForm.get("contact").setValue(this.selectedContact.id);
        this.setTitle(contactId);
      });
    }
}
```

the contactList is not updated and hence selectedContact is null.

I currently has a temporary fix, by introducing this.

```
setTimeout(() => {
          this.producersAgreementForm.get("agreementSigner").setValue(this.selectedAgreementSigner.id);
        }, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I have the feeling that you have not discovered [RxJs operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators) yet. You should only subscribe to Observables at the very end where you need the data (usually in component views). If you need to transform data anywhere along the way then simply use operators to make that transformation:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

contacts(id: number): Observable<Contact[]> {
  return this.sampleSvc.getList(id).pipe(
    map(contacts => {
      return contacts.map(item => {
        return {
          id: item.Id,
          item: item.Description
        };
      });
    })
  )
}
```

With this approach you should not experience the problem that you described anymore.

Comment: Thank you for you response, but need that boolean response as this is tied with other lists. However, I figured my problem, this is not with the code above but how we consumed the results. Thank you.